Buying health insurance though the Marketplace vs directly
I'm considering purchasing a Kaiser Permanente plan, either directly from Kaiser or through the state marketplace. The two plans appear identical, with slightly different names: "Silver HSA X" (direct plan) and "Silver HSA" (marketplace plan). Notably, the monthly premium for the direct plan is about $60 lower.
When I called Kaiser to ask about the price difference, they couldn't explain it and suggested contacting the marketplace instead. However, they stated that both plans offer the same coverage and are both ACA-compliant.
After comparing the Evidence of Coverage documents, I found only minor differences, such as the requirement to make any plan changes through the marketplace vs directly, and some remarks about the premium tax credit. Otherwise, the plans seem identical in terms of coverage. So why is there a price difference? I do not qualify for the premium tax credit, so it makes sense to buy the plan directly from Kaiser. Am I missing something?

I had a similar question here: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/159014/what-are-the-risks-of-buying-health-insurance-directly-and-not-through-the-feder.

Thanks, I saw your questions, and it was helpful, but I was hoping someone could provide an explanation for the price difference.

Unfortunately I never got an answer on my issue. I assume it's one of those weird technical issues that happens with insurance. I'm sure somebody at Kaiser could explain, but I doubt we would be able to reach them to get the answer...

I called Kaiser again today and got the same answer as before. They confirmed that both plans are ACA-compliant and offer identical coverage, but they were unable to explain the price difference.

Non-marketplace plans are offered and priced on wider actuarial factors, including your health history.
By law, marketplace plans are priced based solely on five factors: location, age, tobacco use, plan category (platinum, gold, silver, bronze), and dependents.
Non-marketplace plans can be offered and priced dependent on other factors, including gender, health status, and health history. This is the main factor you are observing.
Non-marketplace plans may exclude some benefits required under the ACA, such as imposing a benefit dollar cap. This is not always true, as you see in your case.
You may find that after a year or two of being on a non-marketplace plan, the insurer may offer you a different, often broader coverage plan, as they gain experience with your claims history. This can be very important, and is worth talking to an agent about.

Thank you for your insightful response! I wanted to add that when I requested a quote for a direct (non-marketplace) plan, both online and over the phone, the only information I needed to provide was my zip code, date of birth, and tobacco use status, which means that their quote couldn't have taken into account other factors like my claim history or individual risk profile.

@panic I think you are underestimating how much data is public knowledge or nearly so.

Gender, zip code, and date of birth may be enough to uniquely identify you.

@Panic I just walked through the Kaiser website. When you enter your zip and age, you get an estimate. When you click the "apply now" button, the first thing they ask you for is your name. Generally, after you give all your information, it will take a few days to go through the underwriting process, during which you can be denied or re-quoted.

I think the main risk is the possibility that your annual income ends up lower than you expect for whatever reason, and you miss out on the premium tax credit that you would have got had you purchased through the Marketplace. You have to weigh the odds of that against the $60 lower monthly premium.
Having gone through a very similar scenario (with Kaiser, no less), I ended up purchasing directly and so far have had no issues, though I haven't used it much yet.


I do not qualify for the premium tax credit, so it makes sense to buy the plan directly from Kaiser. Am I missing something?

I don't know if anyone can tell you if you're missing something without comparing the documents ourselves, but if you're not interested in the tax credit - then as long as you're satisfied with the benefits you can purchase directly. Purchasing through the marketplace is a precondition for the tax credit eligibility (yeah, these "some remarks" you glossed over).

Here's a diff of the two plans: https://draftable.com/compare/ykZseXWPRwAX The marketplace is on the left, and the direct one is on the right. I noticed that the marketplace contains this sentence, that is missing in the other plan, which is a bit concerning: "Kaiser Permanente applies Medicare guidelines for ambulance Services in accordance with the Centers for Medicare and Medicaid Services (CMS)."

I don't claim any specific knowledge here. But it doesn't seem all that mysterious. Presumably the insurance company has some costs complying with the rules of the marketplace, dealing with the bureaucracy, etc. It's not shocking that they would charge a higher premium to cover those costs. In addition, there's simple supply and demand. Most people going through the marketplace are getting a subsidy. If they're not paying the whole cost, they have less reason to be concerned about what the whole cost is.
Frankly, I wouldn't agonize over why the prices are different. In the end, you have a set of choices -- these two plans plus presumably other available plans -- each with certain coverage and certain prices. Pick the plan that gives you the best coverage for the price. Why the insurance company chose to offer that particular policy at that particular price is not really relevant to your decision. Well, except to the extent that the reason tells you something about what you're getting. Like, "they charge less because they don't cover X, Y, and Z".
